# Shortest Path Graph Traversal for Kevin Bacon Game

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I've been trying to create a graph representation for the popular kevin bacon game. I have created the graph and vertex classes, but am having some trouble creating a Breadth first search method to traverse the graph and find the shortest path from Kevin Bacon to the actor, and print out the edges on the way. 
The user should enter in an actor, and the program should find the shortest path from kevin bacon to that actor. The user will then keep entering actors, and the shortest path to that actor will be taken, and the kevin bacon number printed out, else it will print out none.

There is a vertex and graph class. The vertex class is a dictionary which contains the other vertexes it is connected to and the edges.

The data I am working with looks like this:

vertices:

["Kevin Bacon", "actor1", "actor2", "actor3", "actor4", "actor5", "actor6"]

edges:

("Kevin Bacon", "actor1", "movie1")

("Kevin Bacon", "actor2", "movie1")

("actor1", "actor2", "movie1")

("actor1", "actor3", "movie2")

("actor3", "actor2", "movie3")

("actor3", "actor4", "movie4")

("actor5", "actor6", "movie5")

Where the movie is the edge name or weight, and the other parts of the tuple are the vertices. I want the BFS algorithm to print out all of the edges and kevin bacon number, or print out that it is not possible if the actor cannot be reached.

Here is the code so far. Any advice and help is appreciated.

Thank you for your time

```
class Vertex:
    '''
    keep track of the vertices to which it is connected, and the weight of each edge
    '''
    def __init__(self, key):
        '''

        '''
        self.ID = key
        self.connected_to = {}

    def add_neighbor(self, neighbor, weight=0):
        '''
        add a connection from this vertex to anothe
        '''
        self.connected_to[neighbor] = weight

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        returns all of the vertices in the adjacency list, as represented by the connectedTo instance variable
        '''
        return str(self.ID) + ' connected to: ' + str([x.ID for x in self.connected_to])

    def get_connections(self):
        '''
        returns all of the connections for each of the keys
        '''
        return self.connected_to.keys()

    def get_ID(self):
        '''
        returns the current key id
        '''
        return self.ID

    def get_weight(self, neighbor):
        '''
        returns the weight of the edge from this vertex to the vertex passed as a parameter
        '''
        return self.connected_to[neighbor]


class Graph:
    '''
    contains a dictionary that maps vertex names to vertex objects. 
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''

        '''
        self.vert_list = {}
        self.num_vertices = 0

    def __str__(self):
        '''

        '''
        edges = ""
        for vert in self.vert_list.values():
            for vert2 in vert.get_connections():
                edges += "(%s, %s)\n" %(vert.get_ID(), vert2.get_ID())
        return edges

    def add_vertex(self, key):
        '''
        adding vertices to a graph 
        '''
        self.num_vertices = self.num_vertices + 1
        new_vertex = Vertex(key)
        self.vert_list[key] = new_vertex
        return new_vertex

    def get_vertex(self, n):
        '''

        '''
        if n in self.vert_list:
            return self.vert_list[n]
        else:
            return None

    def __contains__(self, n):
        '''
        in operator
        '''
        return n in self.vert_list

    def add_edge(self, f, t, cost=0):
        '''
        connecting one vertex to another
        '''
        if f not in self.vert_list:
            nv = self.add_vertex(f)
        if t not in self.vert_list:
            nv = self.add_vertex(t)
        self.vert_list[f].add_neighbor(self.vert_list[t], cost)

    def get_vertices(self):
        '''
        returns the names of all of the vertices in the graph
        '''
        return self.vert_list.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        '''
        for functionality
        '''
        return iter(self.vert_list.values())

    def bfs(self):
        '''
        Needs to be implemented
        '''
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get an actor
2. Check if the actor is Kevin Bacon
3. If the actor is Kevin Bacon, go back along the path you took
4. If the actor is not Kevin Bacon then find all the actors connected to this actor who you have not already checked.
5. Add all the actors who this actor is connected to to your list to check.

The hardest problem you will have here is keeping a record of which vertexes you have already visited.  As such I think your algorithm should check a list of vertexes. Some assumptions:

- Each vertex is listed only once.
- Vertexes are single direction only.  This means that if you want to go from Actor 1 to Actor 2 and Actor 2 to Actor 1, you need two vertexes, one for each actor essentially.
- You have weights, but I don't see how they're relevant for this.  I'll try to implement them though.  Also your default weight should not be 0, or all paths will be equally short (0*n = 0).

OK lets go.

```
def bfs(self, actor):
    from heapq import heappush, heappop
    if actor == "Kevin Bacon":
        return print("This actor is Kevin Bacon!")
    visited = set()
    checked = []
    n = 0
    heappush(checked, (0, n, [self.get_vertex(actor)]))
    # if the list is empty we haven't been able to find any path
    while checked:
        # note that we pop our current list out of the list of checked lists,
        # if all of the children of this list have been visited it won't be
        # added again
        current_list = heappop(checked)[2]
        current_vertex = current_list[-1]
        if current_vertex.ID == "Kevin Bacon":
            return print(current_list)
        for child in current_vertex.get_connections():
            if child in visited:
                # we've already found a shorter path to this actor
                # don't add this path into the list
                continue
            n += 1
            # make a hash function for the vertexes, probably just
            # the hash of the ID is enough, ptherwise the memory address
            # is used and identical vertices can be visited multiple times
            visited.add(child)
            w = sum(current_list[i].get_weight(current_list[i+1])
                    for i in range(len(current_list)-1))
            heappush(checked, (w, n, current_list + [child]))
    print("no path found!")
```

You should also implement a __repr__() method for your vertex class.  With the one I used, the output looks like this:

```
g = Graph()
for t in [("Kevin Bacon", "actor1", "movie1")
,("Kevin Bacon", "actor2", "movie1")
,("actor1", "actor2", "movie1")
,("actor1", "actor3", "movie2")
,("actor3", "actor2", "movie3")
,("actor3", "actor4", "movie4")
,("actor5", "actor6", "movie5")]:
    g.add_edge(t[0],t[1],cost=1)
    g.add_edge(t[1],t[0],cost=1)

g.bfs("actor4")
# prints [Vertex(actor4), Vertex(actor3), Vertex(actor2), Vertex(Kevin Bacon)]
```

I originally wasn't going to use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html) to do this, but in the end decided I might as well.  Essentially, you need to sort your checked list to get the shortest path first.  The simplest way to do this is to just sort your list every time you want to pop the smallest value off the top, but this can get very slow when your list is getting large.  Heapq can keep the list sorted in a more efficient manner, but there is no key method to get the smallest value of the list we add, so we need to fake it by using a tuple.  The first value in the tuple is the actual cost of the path, while the second one is simply a "tie breaker" so that we do not try to compare Vertexes (which are not ordered and will raise an exception if we try to do so).